# Importing a case insensitive directory

Tags: directory, dropbox, case-insensitive

I am using Ubuntu with a case sensitive file system, and I have downloaded some zipped directories from Dropbox. I assume the zipped directories were created on a case insensitive file system, probably Windows.  When I extract the files, I get multiple version of the directories and sub-directories in different cases. For example, after extracting I have "folder-a" and "Folder-A" which each have some of the contents that should be in the real "Folder-A". The two versions of the directory clearly need to be merged.  Manually, this is tedious once subdirectories get deep.

I'm hoping to answer either one of the two questions:

1. Is there an extraction command which can handle these case issues (I just used right-click->Extract Here)?

OR

2. Is there an easy way to rename and merged these directories recursively?

Comment: If the archive has directory names that are siblings and vary __only__ in case, as the `folder-a` and `Folder-A` in you Q, then it _did not_ come from a Windows system. In Windows you can access the _one_ folder with both variations, and any other case-switched combination you can think of, but when the archive is created, `zip` or otherwise, only the name `as created` will be used. You should recheck whether or not they _should_ be merged or not. I suspect they are somehow different, either in content or intended use. They _might_ have been links, hard or sym, on the original system.